# Why do remote jobs cost more than office jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Looking at the current pricing in CAD, regular job postings cost $649 (CAD), and remote-only jobs cost $1050.  What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Cost as in the cost to list them?

Comment: I assume a combination of a) remote only jobs have far greater reach than most other adverts; and b) the higher cost is intended to dissuade less-than-honest "employers" posting jobs that don't really exist to pad their email lists.

Comment: Advertising your beer to a world of drinkers instead of just Canadians is inevitably more expensive.

Comment: @HansPassant - You seem to put things in the most clearest ways **Cheers**

Comment: @JonH well, isn't clear enough who will be paying the tab... *runs*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments on the question all point to the right answer here:

Remote-only jobs are, by their nature, relevant to a wider audience. Because you're reaching more people / have a larger pool of potential applicants, we charge more for those listings. (Remote-only jobs receive greater distribution through ads on SO and appear in more searches / recommended jobs on the job board.)